# Issues with eclipse & android on win7

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, windows-7

I have searched all over stackoverflow and I can't find the answer that pertains to me.  Here is the scenario.  I have Eclipse Juno installed on a Win7 computer.  Eclipse gets launched from an SD Card that I have.  This SD card also holds the Android SDK and my workspace with all the projects.

I have a specific project that is an Android App.  I can hook my phone up to my Win7 computer, and run the app on my phone via the Run button in Eclipse.  Everything works fine.  Debug, it make changes, still everything is fine.

Now I try to sign the package and get it ready for posting on the market...I go to export, do everything necessary to sign it and hit the finish button (or ok or whatever it is called) to complete the export process.  The finished product SHOULD be an .apk file.  What I get instead, is a Java IO exception that says it can't find some file.  The filename has a bunch of numbers, and the extension is something like

```
 ._pk or .ap_,
```

something like that.

If I take that same project, import it into my workspace on an Ubuntu machine, also running Eclipse Juno.  Do the same process to sign my package and everything works perfectly.

What gives?

I have read other articles that tell you to run Eclipse in Admin mode, Run the Android SDK in admin mode, don't install the sdk to the Program Files directory or some other directory where admin rights are required...

None of that applies to me.  Also, I need to mention that everything, except Win7 is a fresh copy.  Eclipse was downloaded directly from the website, a newly downloaded copy of the Android SDK was downloaded and installed, and all the android classes are newly downloaded via the SDK and eclipse plug-in.

The only difference I can think of between the Eclipse on Linux and the one on Win7 is that it is eclipse Classic on the Linux machine and it is Eclipse w/ Java EE on the Win 7 machine.  Can anyone tell me why this happens, because I spend most of my time on the Win7 machine, and don't want to keep having to swap over to my Ubuntu machine just to sign an Android package...

Comment: Why does running Eclipse in Admin mode not apply to you?  Are you already doing that?  Have you tried cleaning the project before exporting it?

Comment: Because I have done that and it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have also cleaned the project, rebuilt it.  Once I even went so far as to create a brand new project, and copy the code into the new project.  Not the files, mind you, the code in the files.

Comment: A long time ago, back when Eclipse was still on Galileo, everything worked fine.  Then I ran the upgrade for Galileo to Helios, and at the same time upgraded my Android SDK to the newest version.  I think the SDK was something like version 12 or 14, don't remember.  After that upgrade, everything went to hell.  It hasn't worked since.  Even with the fresh installs of everything.

Comment: Have you tried removing your .eclipse and .android folders?

Comment: Flipping brilliant!  Worked like a charm...  Put that as the answer and I will mark it.  FYI for anyone else out there, my .android and .eclipse folders were located in my Windows profile folder...C:\Users\lbailey\

Comment: Wasted months of searching and giving up...such a simple solution...

Comment: I had other weird issues with my setup on Win7 and this turned out to be the fix for that as well!  Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth the answer turned out to be deleteing the .eclipse and .android folders in your user directory.